# Using powershell, is there a way to search a directory for files and folders which have a specified group permission applied?

Tags: powershell

I have a need to familiarize myself with Powershell, and was looking for a point of reference for the particular problem I am trying to solve using Powershell.

To keep it short, awhile back someone gave permissions to 'Everyone' in a public facing web directory with X number of websites running, in a live environment and a lot of files and folders have the permissions applied but it's like finding a needle in a hay stack. We are trying to patch the server for security reasons, and as such need to locate these vulnerabilities (as we have no reason to have these permissions) and I myself have an immediate need to learn Powershell for another project, so I would like to solve this problem with Powershell scripting or Powershell commands. Ultimately exporting the results would be good, but I've found resourced for that.

Can someone provide me a jumping point to start from? I've experience writing batch files, ASP.NET, VB.NET, jQuery, HTML etc...and I can figure out the code I just can't seem to turn any results up by Google.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward. You simply need to get all child directories, recursively, from the root directory (eg. `c:\test`), and then filter that list where the directory's access control list (ACL) contains "*Everyone*."

Here is the code to achieve this:

```
# Get child items (directories only) recursively, where the ACL contains 'Everyone'
Get-ChildItem c:\test -Directory -Recurse | Where-Object -FilterScript { (Get-Acl -Path $PSItem.FullName).AccessToString -match 'Everyone'; };
```